# Managing authentication for my Asp.net MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, security

I am trying to accomplish the following:-

1. To build an Asp.net MVC 4 web application from scratch.
2. I want to use the current users and groups that are found on our company production active directory server.

In asp.net I know that we can have two types of authentication; Form Based & Windows based.

On my development machine I did the following tests:-

1. I set the authentication to be “windows based” and I was be able to access the asp.net MVC application without entering my username and password.
2. I set the authentication to be Form-based and I modify the query string to connect to the Active Directory instead of connecting to the sql databases tables. And I was able to access the application by typing username@domain and the password.

But my questions are:-

1. When deploying the web application on production, how will “windows authentication” works. Let say the user tries to access the application from external device, then can he still login to the system . Or “windows authentication” will not work for internet application.
2. Will form-base authentication connected to AD be the best approach to follow in my case?
3. If “windows authentication” will work when users access the application from external machine. Then what are the differences between having “windows authentication” & Form-based that is connected to an Active directory in this case?

Best Regards